# After Zarafa update all emails were lost

Tags: email, updates

After my Zarafa (Small Business) update to version 7.1.7 all emails were lost. The accounts are still there. 
What can I do to solve the problem quickly?

Answer (score 0):

From which version did you upgrade? What do the Zarafa logs say, specifically /var/log/zarafa/server.log (or if you configured syslog instead, what does that log say)?